# Geometric and algebraic aspects of geometric vectors

Tags: geometry, vectors

I'm writing some notes for a honors physics class and I am having some trouble with some proofs. Say $\vec{A}$ and $\vec{B}$ are some geometric vectors. Then we defined the dot product $\vec{A}\cdot\vec{B}$ as the product of the proyection of $\vec{A}$ onto $\vec{B}$ with the magnitude of $\vec{B}$, and the cross product $\vec{A}\times\vec{B}$ as the vector whose length is the area of the parallelogram defined by $\vec{A}$ and $\vec{B}$ and whose direction was defined through the right hand rule. Then it was easy to show that $\vec{A}\cdot\vec{B}=\|\vec{A}\|\|\vec{B}\|\cos{\theta}$ and $\|\vec{A}\times\vec{B}\|=\|\vec{A}\|\|\vec{B}\|\sin{\theta}$. Non the less, when going to a cartesian coordinate system and writing $$\vec{A}=A_x\hat{i}+A_y\hat{j}+A_z\hat{k}$$ and $$\vec{B}=B_x\hat{i}+B_y\hat{j}+B_z\hat{k}$$I came into some trouble. When trying to show the formula for the dot product I used the argument
$$ \begin{align}
\vec{A}\cdot\vec{B} &=(A_x\hat{i}+A_y\hat{j}+A_z\hat{k})\cdot(B_x\hat{i}+B_y\hat{j}+B_z\hat{k})\\
&=A_x\hat{i}\cdot B_x\hat{i}+A_x\hat{i}\cdot  B_y\hat{j}+A_x\hat{i}\cdot  B_z\hat{k}+A_y  \hat{j}\cdot  B_x\hat{i}+A_y\hat{j}\cdot  B_y\hat{j}+A_y\hat{j}\cdot  B_z\hat{k}+A_z\hat{k}\cdot  B_x\hat{i}+A_z\hat{k}\cdot  B_y\hat{j}+A_z\hat{k}\cdot  B_z\hat{k}\\
&=A_x\hat{i}\cdot B_x\hat{i}+A_y\hat{j}\cdot B_y\hat{j}+A_z\hat{k}\cdot B_z\hat{k}\\
&=A_xB_x+A_yB_y+A_zB_z
\end{align}$$
But I wasn't able to demonstrate from the geometric definition that the dot product obeys the product rule I used in the first step like normal products do (I think I just need to show that the dot product is distributive under addition, I just don't know how). Likewise, I haven't found a convincing argument for the formula
$$\vec{A}\times\vec{B}=\begin{vmatrix}
\hat{i} & \hat{j} & \hat{k} \\
A_x & A_y & A_z \\
B_x & B_y & B_z \\
\end{vmatrix} $$
If anybody could help me prove the formula above and the distribution law under addition for dot products that would be great!
(Side question: how do you write in latex cartesian unit vectors such as $\hat{i}$ so that the dot above the $i$ doesn't appear)

Comment: Search Khan Academy for some videos which explain these results.

Comment: For the latex question use `\hat{\imath}` and `\hat{\jmath}` to get $\hat{\imath}$ and $\hat{\jmath}$.

Comment: Here's the cross product video, linking the determinant to the geometric definition on Khan. https://www.khanacademy.org/math/linear-algebra/vectors_and_spaces/dot_cross_products/v/proof-relationship-between-cross-product-and-sin-of-angle

Answer (score 0):

Just use the same approach as for the dot product, but let $\hat{i}\times\hat{i}=0$, etc.  Let $\hat{i}\times\hat{j}=\hat{k}$, $\hat{j}\times\hat{k}=\hat{i}$, and $\hat{k}\times\hat{i}=\hat{j}$.  Finally let $\hat{i}\times\hat{j}=-\hat{j}\times\hat{i}$ etc.
$$
\begin{align}
\vec{A}\times\vec{B} &=(A_x\hat{i}+A_y\hat{j}+A_z\hat{k})\times(B_x\hat{i}+B_y\hat{j}+B_z\hat{k})\\
&=A_x\hat{i}\times B_x\hat{i}+A_x\hat{i}\times B_y\hat{j}+A_x\hat{i}\times B_z\hat{k}+A_y  \hat{j}\times B_x\hat{i}+A_y\hat{j}\times B_y\hat{j}+A_y\hat{j}\times B_z\hat{k}+A_z\hat{k}\times B_x\hat{i}+A_z\hat{k}\times B_y\hat{j}+A_z\hat{k}\times  B_z\hat{k}\\
&=0+A_x B_y\hat{k} + -A_x B_z\hat{j}+\\
&\;\;-A_y B_x\hat{k} + 0 + A_y B_z\hat{i}+\\
&\;\;\;\;\;\;A_z B_x\hat{j} + -A_z B_y\hat{i}+0\\
&=(A_y B_z -A_z B_y )\hat{i} + (A_z B_x-A_x B_z)\hat{j} + (A_x B_y-A_y B_x)\hat{k}
\end{align}
$$

Which is equal to the determinant that you show.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the answer is here http://math.oregonstate.edu/bridge/papers/dot+cross.pdf
Figures 3 and 8 are the key!!!!!